# Why does this code crash my computer, not just mine but my friends too?

Tags: python

I was practicing writing python code, and I was trying to generate numbers of the Fibonacci series from 1,1,...
I wrote it and it was quite good, but then something odd happened which I write it down here:

```
# Generating Fibonacci Series in a List:
N = 1
M = 1
Fibonacci = []

ChoiceMethod = 0
ChoiceNum = 0
BelowNum = 0

ChoiceMethod = input('Choose Your Method of Work (1/2/3): ')
if int(ChoiceMethod) == 1:
    ChoiceNum = input('Give your Choice Number: ')
    while len(Fibonacci) != int(ChoiceNum):
        Fibonacci.append(N)
        Fibonacci.append(M)
        N += M
        M += N
    print(Fibonacci)
```

You know it's the first part of the code, if you Run the code and enter 1 in the input (1st method) and then when it say Give your Choice Number, for example give it an even number like 2, it will work just fine, like any even numbers. as soon as you give it an odd number like 5, it will crash the PC. and I can't figure out why.
Found a Fix for it too, if you change while "!=" in "len(Fibonacci) != int(ChoiceNum)" to "<" it will work fine but idk what's wrong overally.
I'M TELLING YOU, IT WILL MOST PROBABLY CRASH YOUR PC TOO, Be Careful with it.

Comment: Most likely you run out of ram when your list get stoo big

Comment: You have effectively an infinite loop: because you're always adding two elements to the loop, the length of `Fibonacci` will always be even. If `ChoiceNum` is an odd number, the loop will never exit.

Comment: You append two things to `Fibonacci`, therefore it will always have even length, it can never have length 3 5 7 9 ... - change your condition to `len(Fibonacci) < int(ChoiceNum)`. And no, this does not crash any PC, it will just run into an infinite loop and at some point the *program* will crash.

Comment: @Gray We appreciate your concern for our pcs, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You are causing an infinite loop.

If you introduce an odd number like 5, see that you are adding two numbers at each iteration which means that the length of your Fibonacci list is never going to be odd, it will always be even. For that, you should check the number that you have to introduce and run the loop while checking that max number for your sequence and probably, breaking the loop or adding just 1 element.

Comment: Correct.  The program is an infinite loop, and it will consume all available memory with larger and larger fibonacii numbers.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers explain, there is a bug in your program that means that it is an infinite loop.  So what it actually does is that it builds an ever growing list of ever larger fibonacci numbers.

An infinitely large list requires an infinite amount of memory.  And since the numbers themselves don't have an upper bound, that means even more memory.

But why does it crash your PC?

Well, Python doesn't have any built-in limit on the amount of memory it uses.  So, a pathological Python script like your one will just keep asking the OS for more and more memory.  This is detrimental to the stability of your PC.  A couple of things can happen:

- When the OS runs out of physical RAM, it will start allocating virtual memory.  But virtual memory works by swapping virtual memory pages between physical RAM and your hard disk or SSD.  And the OS typically will grab memory pages from other applications.

  If there is too much swapping going, the paging rate exceeds your system's ability to keep up.  Eventually some vital system service is impacted and ... the system crashes.
- Some operating systems have defenses against programs that generate too much paging activity.  For example, on Linux there is a kernel process called the OOM Killer which tries to identify processes that are creating excessive paging.  When it finds one, it kills it.

  The problem is that the OOM Killer can identify the wrong "culprit".  But if the victim is a vital system service, and the OOM Killer kills it .... crash.

Fortunately, this kind of crash doesn't usually do any long term damage.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Fibonacci = [1, 1]
...
    while len(Fibonacci) != int(ChoiceNum):
        Fibonacci.append(Fibonacci[-2] + Fibonacci[-1])
```

With this loop you will add the sum of last two numbers of your Fibonacci list to the list itself. This way your ChoiceNum can be uneven. !However!, do an extra check to see IF ChoiseNum == 1 return the first value of your Fibonacci list, else do the while loop.